# Clicking my button causes the page to refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just want to ask about the HTML code that why when I click, the Hello world just appear but not stay in my screen?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title> Hello world</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Create a button that when click alert to the screen Hello World-->
  <form>
    <button id="myBtn">Click here</button>
  </form>
  <p id="hi"></p>
  <script>
    let body = document.querySelector('body');
    document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
      body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Submitting a form navigates to a new page

Comment: @David - Remove the form tag and you will be fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There is no reason to wrap your button in a `<form>` tag. You aren't processing a form, you are just using an element to trigger an event listener.

Comment: Change your button to `<button type="button" id="myBtn">`. And BTW, there are hundreds of dupes of this type of question here on SO.

Answer (score 3):

Unintuitively, the implicit [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type) of a `<button>` tag is `submit`, not `button`. So when you have a `<button>` element without a `type` attribute inside a `<form>` element it will cause that form to submit. In this case, your form is lacking an `action` attribute so it will default to submitting to the page you are currently on, which will cause your page to reload.

In this case, the problem is easily resolved by removing the `<form>` tag, because it's not needed for any other reason. But more generally, I would recommend adding a `type="button"` attribute on any `<button>` element that isn't intended to be used to submit a form.

Even if you know in some cases that your button isn't inside a form, it's a useful habit to get into. In some large projects, you might be writing isolated bits of HTML that will get inserted into various contexts, so `type="button"` can prevent bugs from occurring if you create a button in isolation that later gets inserted within a form for some reason.

For completeness, you also have the option of capturing the submit event as the first argument of your event handler, and preventing its default action with the `preventDefault` method:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title> Hello world</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Create a button that when click alert to the screen Hello World-->
  <form>
    <button id="myBtn">Click here</button>
  </form>
  <p id="hi"></p>
  <script>
    let body = document.querySelector('body');
    document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This would prevent default action of the submit event, so the page wouldn't reload even though you clicked a submit button. But because the form element in this case isn't needed for any other reason, it makes more sense to just remove it.

Comment: `Unintuitively, the implicit type of a <button> tag is submit, not button. ` that depends on the point of view. In HTML a `button` that does neither submit nor reset does nothing and is useless. Only by adding scripting such a button starts to make sense. So from the perspective of HtML it makes sense to give a button a default that does something.

Comment: Sure, but if you're making a UI element that has only JavaScript-defined functionality the most semantically correct role is almost always "button", and the only element with this implicit role is `<button>`. In that context, it's very unintuitive that its default type would be "submit". Especially when "button" is another option.